# Basic questions regarding port numbers and firewall

Tags: firewall, internet, port-security

I was studying about how port numbers work and got few questions as follows(sorry but I'm a noob and new to networking stuff but quite interested to learn all this :D )-
 
1. Where all does firewall exist- Server, client or intermediate routers and bridges.
2.What does it mean to add an exception to a firewall.
3.Opening a port means running a service that we want to be accessible to others. For others to use my running service I need to provide them my port number so that they can connect to it. If I am thinking this right way then, where does firewall come into the picture.
4. When I run a `netstat` command on my windows machine then, I see lots services listening on a specific port. I'm not hosting any website so why do I need a service that listens(my pc basically acting as a server). Output looks like this.

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 TCP    0.0.0.0:80             SHIVAM-PC:0            LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:135            SHIVAM-PC:0            LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:445            SHIVAM-PC:0            LISTENING
```

What does listening port 80 mean specifically. I'm not hosting any website for http connections.Why is a service running to that listens on port 80.
Kindly help.

Comment: Sorry, but this question seems to be off-topic here and might be better asked at serverfault.

Comment: But here are some words you might want to use as a base for advanced googling and short answers:

1:) All three, and additional as standalone devices
2:) Allow a specific address to access a port which is generally blocked (or vice versa, depending on firewall design)
3:) I don't understand the question. Firewalls limit access to ports for specific known or unknown clients
4:) If there is a port 80 open on your machine, there is also a service listening to it. 80 is sometimes used for something different than http

Comment: @Sebastian very useful. Thanks alot. Just one thing with which I'm little bit still confused is, when adding a exception to a firewall then we do so at the server side or the client side ?

Comment: That depends on the general design. If it is a local firewall on a server/client, then you'd do it there. If it is a extra firewall for a network, then there.

In general, you change the ruleset of a Firewall where you want the traffic to terminate. So, to allow a host to ping outside where a local firewall denies that, you'd have to make an exception on that host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A firewall can exist in any or all which you have listed, or it can
   be a stand-alone device.
2. By default, a firewall will block all incoming traffic. Adding an
   exception means that you are overriding that behavior for some
   traffic.
3. The meaning of opening a port depends on the context. In the context
   of a firewall, it means creating an exception for traffic destined
   for that port. In the context of an end-device, it means that an
   application has requested that port from the transport-layer
   protocol.
4. As far as the specifics of your OS listening to ports, you will need
   to ask that question somewhere else, such as [Super User](https://superuser.com/) since
   it is off topic here because it involves
   applications/application-layer protocols, and different OSes may
   have different needs for listening on ports.